# How to make the vuelidate alpha vuejs3 to have the global $v function instead of declare in every vue file?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuelidate

I am running a project using vue3 and trying with vuelidate alpha version.

I declare the `vuelidatePlugin` in main.js:

```js
//main.js

import { VuelidatePlugin } from "@vuelidate/core";
...

app.use(VuelidatePlugin)
```

This part was successful. Then go into each vue file and declare this below in order to make the `v` working for check error.

```
...
 setup () {
        // this will collect all nested component’s validation results
        const $v = useVuelidate()
    
        return { $v }
      },
...
```

How could I declare this in main.js and use `$v` in every vue file without declaring it again in `setup`?